# Java apache POI set metadata

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to generate excel reports. But the properties of the excel file clearly mention that I have used `Apache POI`. I want to mention my software name instead here

[image]

This is my current code, where I'm trying to set a custom property but it's not working.

```
 XSSFWorkbook xlsxSetMetadata = new XSSFWorkbook();
 xlsxSetMetadata.createSheet("Test sheet");
 POIXMLProperties props = xlsxSetMetadata.getProperties();

 POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProp=props.getCoreProperties();
 coreProp.setCreator("---------------");
 coreProp.setDescription("Report");
 coreProp.setKeywords("Report ");
 coreProp.setTitle("... Report");

 POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties extProp=props.getExtendedProperties();
 extProp.getUnderlyingProperties().setCompany("XYX company");
 extProp.getUnderlyingProperties().setTemplate("XSSF");

 POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties custProp = props.getCustomProperties();
 custProp.addProperty("Author", "..........");
 custProp.addProperty("Program name", "MY_SOFTWARE_NAME_HERE");

 String fname = "file_name.xlsx";
 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fname);
 xlsxSetMetadata.write(out);
 out.close();
```

How can I change the `program name` property to my program name ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
extProp.getUnderlyingProperties().setApplication("MY_SOFTWARE_NAME_HERE");
```

under the `POIXMLProperties.ExtendedProperties`.

Taken from [this thread](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-write-the-metadata-into-the-document-tp3309193p3310376.html)